# What are reasons a mer-person might speak English?

Tags: language, merfolk, sea-creatures

If such a thing would even be possible.

Comment: Why not English?  This seems rather broad at the moment.  We don't know anything about your merpeople's culture or physical capabilities.  The traditional assumption is that merpeople have the same kind of vocal cords as humans and could learn any human language.

Comment: Yes; too broad to answer meaningfully.

Comment: We need to know more about merfolk and the world they live in to give you a good answer. As it is now, everything is possible.

Comment: Why do many Europeans, Japanese, Chinese, &c speak English?

Comment: @jamesqf To be able to talk to native English speakers who are too lazy to learn Japanese, Chinese or European languages. Also, non-English speakers have a wonderful fluency in learning other languages, so why not English too.

Comment: @a4android: The "lazy" is not entirely fair, as there's a limit to the number of languages one person can learn.  I might have studied Latin, French, Spanish, Japanese, and Finnish (college girlfriend :-)), but that doesn't do much good if I find myself in Germany or China.  OTOH, the research lab I worked at in Switzerland had people from all over the world, so the default language was English.

Comment: @jamesqf My comment wasn't aimed at people like yourself. I know too many Anglophones who avoid learning other languages because everybody else will speak English. While many, for example, Europeans learn remarkable numbers of languages. Indigenous Australians often know multiple languages. Personally I have smatterings of German, Latin, Japanese and Chinese, but don't claim to be fluent. That's my loss.

Comment: @a4android: But for most Americans, everyone else within reasonable travelling distance DOES speak English.  It's not like Europe, where I could bike between 3 different languages in a couple of days.

Comment: @jamesqf I'm not American. My gripe was more with Brits and Aussies who harbour the belief that everybody should speak English with expectation the whole world will eventually be Anglophone. They'd weep buckets if Japanese or Mandarin or Hindi became the global *lingua franca*. Once Latin was the universal European language & French the language of diplomacy. Things change, they will change again.

Answer (score 5):

All you need for this is proximity to English-speaking people.  If there's proximity, there will be conflict, or potential conflict which can be avoided through communication.

Some thoughts:

- Merfolk might be *very territorial* about their favorite fishing grounds.  "You can fish *here*, but not *there*, landlubbers!"
- Merfolk might have a habit of rescuing shipwrecked sailors.  Over time they've learned to communicate with these flotsam-folk so as to not freak them out.
- Could be they desire trade with the humans.  They could trade shipwreck treasure, exotic corals, or heck, fish to the humans in exchange for metals and ceramics.
- There could be a protection racket going on.  "Nice ship you have there, human.  Be a shame if something ... happened to it."
- Might be that merfolk all know English, but nobody on land knew, because merfolk lore maintains that "the men up there don't like a lot of chatter"...

Comment: Nice Ursula reference!

Comment: @Will I tried to resist putting in that last bullet point, but I couldn't.  I just **couldn't**.  ;D

Answer (score 1):

I see several.

1. Merfolk are magically transformed (english speaking) humans.
2. Merfolk could have no useful language of their own, and have discovered english, and have adopted it. The same could be true of clothing, makeup, and Viagra.
3. akaioi's answer.
4. Coincidence.
5. English speaking humans captured pet merfolk, taught them english, and then released them, much as dolphins in *Day of the Dolphin* were taught certain sounds.

I think it is more of a problem to have *verbal language* underwater in the sense you are asking for an air-driven mechanism to exist, where air is absent.  But you don't seem to be asking about that very basic problem. So, they likely have english, and viagra, and boob jobs too. Why not.

Comment: DPT, traditionally merfolk are supposed to be (ahem) beautifully proportioned, hence not in need of either plastic surgery or viagra.  More realistically, to survive that cold ocean merfolk should have a glorious, thick layer of blubber!  Like almost all marine mammals.

Comment: The blubber is good. They damn well better be able to sing.

Comment: I bet they can, but with our luck it'll be in super high-frequency sonar ranges that humans can't hear... ;D

Answer (score 0):

**Sirens.**
If you want sailors to jump overboard when they hear you, it helps if the sailors understand what you are singing.

Ulysses and the Sirens.   https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Herbert_James_Draper
[image: Drapers Ulysses and the sirens]

http://classics.mit.edu/Homer/odyssey.12.xii.html

> If any one unwarily draws in too close and hears the singing of the
>   Sirens, his wife and children will never welcome him home again, for
>   they sit in a green field and warble him to death with the sweetness
>   of their song. There is a great heap of dead men's bones lying all
>   around, with the flesh still rotting off them. Therefore pass these
>   Sirens by, and stop your men's ears with wax that none of them may
>   hear; but if you like you can listen yourself, for you may get the men
>   to bind you as you stand upright on a cross-piece half way up the
>   mast, and they must lash the rope's ends to the mast itself, that you
>   may have the pleasure of listening. If you beg and pray the men to
>   unloose you, then they must bind you faster.

Look at Ulysses.  He definitely hears them.  I wonder if later in his life he ever dreamt of that song and woke up as he was walking down the road to go to them.